# Nodejs chproc as simple user and not root

Tags: linux, node.js, exec, root

Hi this may be a simple question but i can't figure out how could I, using chproc.exec open an application, but my current program is running as root and I need the childprocess to run as a user.
How Could I achieve that? 
Current code :

```
chproc.exec("google-chrome").unref();
```